# How to initialize a private variable in a final class using REFLECTION or any other API?

Tags: java, reflection, junit, mockito, powermock

This may sound awkward but I am trying to initialize a private variable in a final class. I've done this many times and I know it works very well using `Reflection` but I have never really done this with a final class. Since I cannot instantiate the class i cannot pass any object to set the variable and this is where I am stuck.

Final class

```
public final class LoggingHandler implements ILoggingHandler {

private Log generalLog; 

/**
 * @param log The general log.
 */
private void setGeneralLog(Log log) {
    generalLog = log;
}

/**
 * @return The general log.
 */
private Log getGeneralLog() {
    return generalLog;
}
```

JUnit

```
@Test
public void testSendDocuments() throws Exception {
    AppContext.setApplicationContext( applicationContext );
    IClientUserDto iClientUserDto = mock( IClientUserDto.class );

    DocusignRESTProvider docusignRestProvider = new DocusignRESTProvider();
    docusignRestProvider.setLoggingHandler( iloggingHandler );
    docusignRestProvider.setDocumentManager( iDocumentManager );
    docusignRestProvider.setConfiguration( iProviderConfiguration );
    docusignRestProvider.setManager( iManager );

    Field field = LoggingHandler.class.getDeclaredField( "generalLog" );
    field.setAccessible( true );
    field.set( new Object(), log );

    when( iTransformer.transformRequest( any( SendDocumentsTransformerArgs.class ) ) ).thenReturn( iTransformerResult );
    docusignRestProvider.sendDocuments( iClientUserDto, iDocumentSet );
}
```

`log` is a mocked object.

stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.apache.commons.logging.Log field com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.common.logging.LoggingHandler.generalLog to java.lang.Object
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
at test.com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.provider.docusign.rest.TestDocusignRESTProvider.testSendDocuments(TestDocusignRESTProvider.java:167)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Can someone let me know what other approach is there to test such a condition and how?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you create an instance of a `LoggingHandler`? Does it have a private constructor? How about instantiating it via reflection?

Comment: This is the whole point. Final classes cannot be instantiated. And, yes it has a private invisible constructor.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but `final` classes cannot be **extended**. `String` is `final`, but it surely can be instantiated (try `new String()`)

Comment: They can but not with private constructor.

Comment: If reflection is acceptable you can call a private constructor. Yet I expect that at least a singleton instance (or a public factory method) of this class exists. And you can also set the field of this singleton instance/result of the factory method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the concept of a `final` class. Final classes CAN be instantiated, they cannot be inherited.
So, in your case `LoggingHandler` can and should be instantiated unless its constructor is private. But if its constructor is private - what is the point of such a class implementing an interface?

You should create public setters and getters for `Log` field, instantiate a `LoggingHandler` instance and pass there a mock of you `Log` object within test. You can do whatever verifications you need on that mock later.

Comment: The problem is that the constructor is private, Class is completely singleton.

Comment: I guess this is what I need to do, because I don't see any proper usage of it.